# Hit ctrl+c during installing ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop, but I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> during installation by mistake.
The installation have been frozen for almost 1 hour.

What should I do?

Comment: Force shut down and start over, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have killed the installation process, so just shut down the computer and restart the install.